# HTTP Error 500 using CE_Image

Tags: expressionengine

I've recently moved my working site to a staging environment, and now, some channels display an internal server error (500) while others work flawlessly. Nothing appears to have changed.

Is there some setting I've missed or might this have to do with a different PHP version on the staging server? Something else?

Edit 9/21:

**I think I've narrowed it down to a CE_Image issue...it occurs on every template using CE_Image**

Here's an example of some template code that, if removed, causes the errors to go away:

```
    {cf_home_slideshow limit="5"}
        <li data-slide="slide_{row_count}" style="background-image: url({exp:ce_img:pair allow_scale_larger="yes" src="{cf_image}" max_width="956" max_height="429" create_tag="no" crop="yes"}{made}{/exp:ce_img:pair})"> 
            <a href="{cf_link}"><img src="{exp:ce_img:pair allow_scale_larger="yes" src="{cf_image}" max_width="956" max_height="429" create_tag="no" crop="yes"}{made}{/exp:ce_img:pair}" width="956" height="429" /></a>
            <div class="slide">
                {if cf_link}
                <div class="view_project">
                <a href="{cf_link}" class="button">View Project <img src="/assets/imgs/arrow_btn.png"></a>
                </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
        </li>
    {/cf_home_slideshow}
```

Comment: Can you offer examples of working and non-working `exp:channel:entries` loops on staging?

Comment: I would think that most causes of 500 errors would be lower down in the application stack than EE. I'd start by looking at my Apache Server .conf files and any .htaccess files.  One way to test would be to duplicate and rename a template or template group that was giving errors.  Does it still give errors with the new name?  Conversely duplicate a working template and give it the name of a non-working template.  If the same code can give different results by only changing names you've eliminated the code itself as the cause of the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! Resolved.

GD Library wasn't installed. When I installed it, all was well!